# In jMeter, how to update a parameter value on each occurrence?

Tags: jmeter

I'm facing a situation where I need to build a request string dynamically before sending it in an HTTP sampler. I'm choosing a random number between 15 and 50, and then for that many times, I append an XML tag with a parameter. So if my random number is 22, the this appended string (I call it ricString) will contain the same xml tag 22 times! And all I want is for it to use 22 different parameter values from the CSV file. But it doesn't do that. It takes the same value 22 times, and then uses the next value in the next iteration. Here is what I have written in my beanshell pre-processor.

```
counter = ${__Random(15,50)};
i = 0;
String ricString;

while(i<counter)
{
    i++;
    ricString = ricString + "<req:RCS>${__StringFromFile(...\RIC_3_01_Flag.csv)}</req:RCS>";
}
```

I have tried using both *__StringFromFile* as well as *__CSVRead(filename, next)* functions but no luck. It just does not update the value when inside the while-loop. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [CSV DataSet](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) that you nest into your loop (this is very important).

Then just use that variable that your CSV DataSet defines in your XML.